# Taking a break from computer use

Tags: web-apps, health

Someone recommended a program called [Eyes Relax](http://themech.net/eyesrelax/) to me.  I have not heard much about that and can't check if it's safe, it's not a commonly used application apparently.  I don't want to install it before I know for sure.  I posted it elsewhere on Stack Exchange but was suggested to post my question here.

First, if anybody heard of that application and can tell me if it's safe to install on my computer, like 100% safe.

Secondly, if there are better applications that tell you to take a break when you been using computer on a regular basis, maybe every x minutes and then lock the screen for instance.  Now I have Windows 10 and use Firefox so a FF extension would be fine too, so in short, web-apps, FF extensions, or software for Windows are okay, my focus being on the program itself (safety, usefulness, bells and whistles).

I prefer suggestions from people who have used the application they recommend, and can tell me the work for sure and are 100% safe (I've had a virus before and can't go through that again).  Thanks!

Comment: You added the tag [tag:web-apps], and you would prefer it to be for Firefox -- does that mean you are looking for a Web app? Or a Firefox add-on? Or software for your OS (Windows?), so that it works also for other programs than Firefox? -- Regarding features: What do you mean with "regular basis"? Every *x* minutes? Is a notification enough, or should the screen get locked or something similar? -- Please [edit] your question and include the details.

Comment: Asking whether a program *is safe* can never be answered definitively. Use an up-to-date virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I use [EyeLeo](http://eyeleo.com/), It has options for setting short and long breaks, break duration, break notifications and strict mode. The breaks will remind you to stretch and move your eyes around. It can easily be disabled temporary or start a break early.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WorkRave](http://www.workrave.org/). It's intended as an anti-RSI program, but if you follow its break and exercise suggestions while *not* looking at the screen (that should be possible after you have memorized them) it is fit for your purpose.

It is one of the better-known programs in this area, but whether it's *safe* can never be answered definitely. Theoretically someone could have hacked it between the time I write this and the time you download it.